# ActionListener Class Can't get Values From Another Class

Tags: java, actionlistener

I'm having trouble with calling a get method from one class and implementing it in a seperate actionlistner class. Here is the code for my get method which gets the text from a JTextField.

```
public String getTitleTextField() {
    return this.TitleTextField.getText();
}
```

The button that calls the listner class is below:

```
this.AddButton = new JButton("Add");
AddButton.setBounds(20, 161, 89, 23);
AddButton.addActionListener(new Listener());
add(AddButton);
```

Here is the code for my listner class:
`

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Listener implements ActionListener{

    FilmPanel view;
    SaveData save;
    Object[] row = new Object[1];

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        row[0] = view.getTitleTextField();
        view.model.addRow(row);
        try {
            save.saveTable();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };
}
```

The error comes up as

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at assignment.listener.actionPerformed(listener.java:13)
```

which points to this `row[0] = view.getTitleTextField();`

Thanks for any help :)

EDIT:

Trying to figure out what's wrong its not a NULL exception

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: How is that a duplicate?

Comment: When is`view` set? `FilmPanel view;` means `view` will get the value `null`, which explains the `NullPointerException`

Comment: @user123123123 how is that not a duplicate?

Comment: @Stefan FIlmPanel is the Class name for where the get methods are and the GUI is

Comment: `FilmPanel` is the class. You have to make sure your `view` object is set so it "points" to the object that is your current instance of `FilmPanel`. Maybe a bit confusing since you're only working with one `FilmPanel` object, but image you had 10 windows/views next to each other. How would the `view` in the listener know which of the 10 objects to listen to?

Comment: @Stefan how would I overcome this?

Comment: Pretty simple actually. Just check whether `view.getTitleTextField();´ is already initialized or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a reference to this when you create the Listener:

```
new Listener(this); // instead of new Listener() in your code
```

Add a constructor in the Listener:

```
public Listener(FilmPanel view) {
    super();
    this.view = view;
}
```

Comment: I'm happy to help :)

Comment: Just a note referring to the original question. There is also a field `SaveData save` which isn't initialised just like `FilmView view` wasn't. However, your exception handling will hide this error. But perhaps your aware of this already and the reason the exception handling is there is because it still needs to be implemented.